# Use link from email outlook to fire VBA code

Tags: vba, outlook

is there any chance to make the following scenario working

1. user gets email in Outlook containing link/text/object
2. clicking the object runs simple VBA code (i.e. replace string in txt) file on users computer

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. This is a potential path for malware.

Instead, you can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class in Outlook VBA macros where can detect such mails (with a specific text or links) and run your business logic accordingly.

The `NewMailEx` event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Comment: Thank you. Let me make it more clear, I basically need approve/decline button in email. The method you're suggesting doesn't provide possibility to make decision by user, also the email receive event sounds not doable, as user should be able to choose on his own when he wants to work with approvals. Are there any other methods, addins or maybe even completely out of box different soultions in your opinion?

Comment: You can display a dialog to a user for confirming any actions.